# Find a record by bigint column with wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an API that has a database with UPC-12 values in it. Sometimes API calls will come in with UPC-10 codes. My db upc column is `bigint`, so it removes the leading `0` on a UPC-12 value. That leaves the last digit as a wildcard when comparing to UPC-10.

I'd like to be able to check a UPC-10 value against records in the db to see if there's a match. Since I can't use `LIKE`, how do I do that?

The goal is to do something like:

```
def self.pull_product(upc)
    upc_string = upc.to_s

    if upc_string.length == 10
        # product = Product.where...  use a wildcard to try and match to existing record
    else
        product = Product.find_by_upc(upc)
    end
end
```

This Rails 4 and Postgresql.

Just to clarify:

I might have a UPC-10 api call with a upc param like: `7618600002`. My database has the UPC-12 equivalent: `76186000023`. So if I just query for the param in the api call, I'll get nil.

I need a way to match the the UPC-10 param against my UPC-12 value in the database.

Comment: do you think about just `where(upc: upc_string.to_i)`?

Comment: Why can't you use LIKE?

Comment: My understanding is that LIKE is for string/text. I tried with bigint and it did not work. I could be wrong, do you have a working example? @МалъСкрылевъ That's essentailly what `else` returns. Perhaps check the question again to understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you use a upc-datatype when you have to store upc values? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/isn.html

Comment: @settheline not quite understood, could you add an example?

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for the tip on that. Unfortunately a lot of my data is from third party input and can often not be as clean as I'd like - making it tough to validate some of the data as ISN data (per the link you shared). Not sure how that would solve my present issue though.

Comment: Updated with an example @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: Just `SELECT * FROM upc WHERE upc::text LIKE '7618600002_'`. If the performance is important, you can use `SELECT * FROM upc WHERE upc::text LIKE '7618600002_' AND UPC BETWEEN 10 * 7618600002 AND 11* 7618600002;` which makes use of an index on BIGINTs, or you can create an additional index on column values casted to strings: `CREATE INDEX xxx ON upc(cast( upc as text));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL like this:

```
upc between upc_string::int*10 and upc_string::int*10+9
```

I have no idea how to code it in Rails though.

Comment: If this is what the OP is looking for, you could write in Rails as `Product.where("? between upc_string::int*10 and upc_string::int*10+9", upc).first`